# Breakpoint cannot be stepped into

Tags: breakpoints

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s408v.png)
"When I click on this item to enter the webpage, I can't execute the step into operation?"

"I hope to be able to execute the step into operation in PyCharm when opening the webpage."